# mvc3 cshtml razor and if statement how to use it in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@foreach (var articleOnFirstPage in Model.ArticlesOnFirstSite)
{
    <td> 
    if (@article.Deleted == true) 
    {   
        @:Yes
    }
    else
    {
        @:No
    }
    </td>
}
```

can i do this like `@article.Deleted == true ? @:Yes : @:No` ?

i try but i get error. Is there any good web page with this examples for mvc3 razor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do:

```
@(article.Deleted ? "Yes" : "No")
```